# SwiftUI: scroll to in ScrollView of both axis

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview

I am making app with ScrollView of both axis, vertical and horizontal, and I have a lot of items in it. After clicking one of them I want to center it on screen. But classic ScrollViewReader with scrollTo function doesn't work as I want to.

This is code of test view:

```
struct Test2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]){
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                VStack(spacing: 100){
                    ForEach(1..<50){ i in
                        Button(action: {
                            proxy.scrollTo(i, anchor: .center)
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Number \(i)")
                        }).padding(.leading, Double(i)*50)
                            .id(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Scroll view reader goes on the outside of the scroll view

Comment: Yeah but It still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: <Rhetorical question>
Why does every tutorial/example/etc., including Apple tell us to "embed the ScrollViewReader in the ScrollView"?  When that is wrong. 
</Rhetorical question>

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little bit like cheating but hey it works

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]){
            
            VStack(spacing: 100){
                    ForEach(1..<50){ i in
                        Button(action: {
                            proxy.scrollTo(i, anchor: .trailing)
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Number \(i)")
                                .frame(width: 100)
                        })
                        .padding(.trailing, (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 50)
                        // just adapt here the measure of your view instead of ^^ 50 which is half of the text with
                        .padding(.leading, Double(i)*50)
                            .id(i)
                    }
                }
            
            } //: ScrollView
        } //: ScrollViewReader
```

Comment: It's working just for this example and I want it to be adjustable to any type of content inside the scroll view

Comment: What kind of content? If it's a view it should be fine, you add half of the screen padding trailing to your view so it's nicely centered horizontally and than on click it scrolls to the trailing of the view, which is already on the center